# Context is always nil using jsonapi-resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-resources

Using version `0.6.0` of the jsonapi-resources gem in conjuction with Doorkeeper I am having a problem seeing the current user in the `context` object in my resource.

I am basically following [the docs](https://github.com/cerebris/jsonapi-resources#fetchable-attributes), however nothing I try will make the `context` I set in `ApplicationController` visible in the resource's `fetchable_fields` method.  I did confirm that `context` is actually being set in my `ApplicationController`.

Here is what I have

ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def context
    {current_user: current_user}
  end
end
```

Controller

```
class Api::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
end
```

Resource

```
class Api::ItemResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  # attributes

  def fetchable_fields
    # context is always nil here
    if (context[:current_user].guest)
      super - [:field_i_want_private]
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this, I am running up against something similar?

Comment: I did not @withakay.  I ultimately didn't need to do this but we should probably open an issue in github since it seems unlikely to get addressed here.

Comment: I guess `:doorkeeper_authorize!` has a method called `current_user`? Are you sure it works properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, using the [jsonapi-utils](https://github.com/b2beauty/jsonapi-utils) gem – that is created on top of jsonapi-resources – you would write something like this:

ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < JSONAPI::ResourceController
  include JSONAPI::Utils
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

ItemsController:

```
class API::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!
  before_action :load_user

  def index
    jsonapi_render json: @user.items
  end

  private

  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

No need to define context :-)

I hope it helps you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Taking your example, here is my solution

Resource

```
class Api::ItemResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  # attributes

  def fetchable_fields
    # context is always nil here
    if (context[:current_user].guest)
      super - [:field_i_want_private]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  # upgrade
  def self.create(context)
    # You can use association here but not with association table
    # only works when `id` is inside the table of the resource
    ItemResource.new(Item.new, context)
  end

  before_save do
    # Context is now available with `self.context`
    self.context[:current_user]
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not need a `context` method in the `ApplicationController`. The context is actually available in the `Resource` class through the framework. In your resource, you can access:

```
@context[:current_user]
```

Comment: What? So where does current_user come from if not the controller?

Comment: Context on the resources is not available with Doorkeeper